# Windows 10: High disk activity on external disk during reboot - How do I find the cause?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, reboot

When I reboot my computer, it gets stuck on the "restarting" spinning wheel for about 10-12 minutes before it finally soft-reboots or shuts down. During this time, my external hard-drive is going crazy with activity. So it's clearly doing something that takes a long time before it can finally reboot/shutdown. Is there a way I can debug or find out what exactly is causing it and what it's doing? So I can make my reboots less insufferable.

When I unplug my external drive, it reboots almost instantly. However, because my external drive also contains a lot of project files and stuff for work, I can't simply leave it unplugged.

**So again, is there a way for me to figure out what the external disk is doing during reboots?**

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour if you detach the drive via system tray?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4051300/windows-10-safely-remove-hardware

Comment: @CraftyB When I attempt do that: I just get an error saying the device is currently in use. So that doesn't work.

Comment: Ok are you using any particular software for the projects you have stored on the drive?

Comment: @CraftyB All the software I use are closed down during the time I tried to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a program called Process Monitor from Microsoft Sysinternals and make a filter in the program that only shows activity on the drive in question. From the list you will see what processes generate the activity. Here is a link to the program: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Is it possible for Process Monitor to actually log the disk activity to a file somewhere while the system is rebooting? It will be a little difficult to use Process Monitor while the system is rebooting... Unless it can log of course.

Comment: It creates a backing file and logs the events into that but I don't know how it behaves after a reboot started.

Comment: I don't think it would help in that case. Since all this activity occurs after all the programs are shut down and the user is signed out. It happens during the very last stage before the soft restart is triggered.

Comment: Options > Enable boot logging, and prepare for a very long boot.

Comment: I consider "cannot eject drive because files are in use" as the same issue. Put your system in a state as if you are about to shut down, then identify open handles using process explorer: search for the drive letter (e.g. "d:\") in the file handle dialog.